# Navbar dropdown moving to extreme left after putting $('#header').load('header.html') script

Tags: javascript, html, css

My navbar dropdown is moving towards the extreme left and also not opening properly after adding this script, when i remove the script and run it like a normal static html page it is running completely fine, Please help if you can, it would save me a lot of time in this

```js
$(function() {
  $('#header').load('header.html');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
</script>

HERE IS HTML OF MY NAVBAR

<header class="header-area">
  <div class="main-header-area">
    <div class="classy-nav-container breakpoint-off">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Classy Menu -->
        <nav class="classy-navbar justify-content-between" id="robertoNav">

          <!-- Logo -->
          <a class="nav-brand" href="#"><img src="./img/core-img/logo.png" alt=""></a>

          <!-- Navbar Toggler -->
          <div class="classy-navbar-toggler">
            <span class="navbarToggler"><span></span><span></span><span></span></span>
          </div>

          <!-- Menu -->
          <div class="classy-menu">
            <!-- Menu Close Button -->
            <div class="classycloseIcon">
              <div class="cross-wrap"><span class="top"></span><span class="bottom"></span></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Nav Start -->
            <div class="classynav">
              <ul id="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about" title="About us">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" title="Products">Products</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="link.html">Item</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="link.html">Dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="link.html">Dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="link.html">Dropdown</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="link.html">-Double Width Tower</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="link.html">Dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="link.html">Dropdown</a></li>

                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="link.html">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link.html">Item</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="link.html">dropdow</a></li>
                        <li><a href="link.html">dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="link.html">dropdown</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="link.html">-other accessories</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="link.html">dropdown</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="link.html">Ladders</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="link.html">dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link.html">dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link.html">dropdown</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="link.html">Accessories</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="link.html/">- dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link.html">- dropdown Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link.html">- dropdown</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="contact.html" title="contact us">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Nav End -->
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi do you have a JsFiddle or Codepen link we can look at?

Comment: Your drop down is not working with or without script! Did I broke your code?